# Adding s3 bucket folder's address to output bucket + python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

How do I link my s3 bucket folder to output bucket in python?

I tried several permutation and combination but it still didn't work out. All I need is to link my folder address to output bucket in python.

I found error when I tried below combination -

```
output Bucket = "s3-bucket.folder-name"
output Bucket = "s3-bucket/folder-name/"
output Bucket = "s3-bucket\folder-name\"
```

None from the above worked, throws an error as -

```
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "s3-bucket/folder-name/": Bucket name must match the 
regex "^[a-z A-Z 0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"
```

Is there any alternate way to put the folder address into python script?
Please help!

Comment: The error says white space is not allowed in bucket name. Kindly rename your folder and S3 bucket so that there are no spaces in the name

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `output Bucket = ...`? Can you show us more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

In AWS, the "folder", or the object file path, is all part of the object **key**.

So when accessing a bucket you specify the bucket name, which is strictly the bucket name with nothing else, and then the object key would be the file path.